# How to create a horizontal scrolling view on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a horizontal scrolling field at the top of a UITableView (something similar to what can be found on the Home section of the Facebook App).

I want the scrolling field to be filled with six sections where only one section could be selected at a time?

How should i do this?

I know i should create a UIScrollView and set it to the header view of the table, but i am having trouble seeing the scroll bars or seeing it actually scroll horizontally.  What visual objects should i use to represent the six sections and to ensure that only one section can be selected at a time (i know i could probably use a segmented control, but i want the section to look more like labels)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Facebook app's tab views are [open source](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) (Apache licensed).  Check out `TTTabStrip`.

Comment: wait just as a clarification i can use this in an application that i want to sell in the App Store?? I am surprised I have no seen other apps beside FaceBook use it.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in your own app.  You don't even need to credit it.

Comment: great resource - but has TTTabStrip been removed? Couldn't see a class for it.

Comment: It's there - just declared in TTTabBar.[hm].