# How to create a horizontal scroll in iphone app

Tags: iphone, horizontal-scrolling

i want to create view like, i have more than 20 icons on top and i want to chose icons with horizontal scroll but i am very much concerned about how to create horizontal scroll view in my application.

i appreciate your time , please help me on this with any examples.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you need the horizontal scroll as in this following app demo,
[Sky News App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3XmIaXVwNY)

I am also trying the same, here are my reference, hope this is useful to you,

1. thread - 
   //[stackoverflow.com/questions/822792/how-to-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-view-on-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822792/how-to-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-view-on-iphone)
2. demo with sample code - 
   //[blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/)

If I got the solution first, i will give you. 
If you got it first, pls let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

As isharan said, addSubviews to UIScrollView and setContentSize for UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

transform the tableview