# iPhone:How to create scrollview in a tollbar which is placed under(below) navigation bar?

Tags: iphone

How to create scrollview in a toolbar which is under(just below) navigation bar, same like shown in the image which is available there in the below http link. Please see the image where it located in the below link, and a scrollview created(Tabs are "Video, US, World" etc.) under "My Title" navigation bar. Could someone guide me how can i add scrollview in the toolbar which is under a navigation bar?

Thank you.

Image Link:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?89c222772d.png

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822792/how-to-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-view-on-iphone

Comment: Hi Kenny, This is definitely not a duplicate of what you are referring.

Comment: Hi Kenny, sorry. i recognize now that it could be duplicate of the one you have mentioned in your link. sorry. Facebook sample catalog tab is the one what i was expecting. thank you.

Comment: @Getsy Today I ve to develop the same UI as u. What u apply for your case.. Share yours ideas with me