# iPhone: objc_class_name_TTTabStrip symbol not found build error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement 'scrollview' effect in 'Tabbar' which has 'TabItems'. I found that the good example is from 'facebook' open source 'TTCatlog' project 'Tabs' section.
So i included all the source from it to my project and trying to build it. 
I have followed the following links to go ahead on this:
[How to create a horizontal scrolling view on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822792/how-to-create-a-horizontal-scrolling-view-on-iphone)
source: http://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/

My calling code is like below:

```
_tabBar1 = [[TTTabStrip alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 68, 300, 28)];
_tabBar1.tabItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 1"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 2"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 3"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 4"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 5"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 6"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 7"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 8"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 9"] autorelease],
                     [[[TTTabItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item 10"] autorelease],
                     nil];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_tabBar1];
```

My project folder as like below:

..../iphone/MyProgram/MyProgram.xcodeproj

..../iphone/Three20/src/Three20....

In my project settings for header search path, I have

../Three20/src

But when i try to build it, it throws the following error:

"objc_class_name_TTTabStrip symbol not found"
"objc_class_name_TTTabItem symbol not found" 
I see there, all these files (.h and .m) are availbale there.

Could someone please help what's wrong there and how do i get rid of this issue and continue working with it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error throw due to  you not importing the appropriate class where you want to implement
the method of that class(like inheritance).

`#import "your_class_name.h"`

`@class your_class_name`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain , do i need to add two things here? #import <.h> and 
@class my_class_name

?

Comment: I tried adding like below:

@class TTTabStrip;

@class TTTabItem;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

}

But still no luck, observing the same build errors.

Comment: I resolved build error by following the steps from the link: http://github.com/facebook/three20